# Can't expand Numpy arrays in VSCode

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I've been using VSCode for more than a year with Python. Never had a problem expanding Numpy arrays to view the elements of the array until the last VSCode update. Now that capability has disappeared for me. Anyone else experiencing this problem?

What I tried is simple. I hit a breakpoint and added a Numpy array to the Watch list. When I click to expand the variable I do see the Numpy members. However, there is no way to view the actual elements of the array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I posted to GitHub for VSCode. The issue is being addressed there. I withdraw the issue from Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can share your GitHub link here so that more followers can learn about the development and solutions to the problem. You can also post the solution as an answer.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Comment: This is a bug in the latest release of the Python extension for VS Code. The extension is provided by Microsoft. I have no idea if they plan to address it.

Comment: You can share your GitHub link here.